# Using a stepper motor with a photo sensor and a "toggle"

Tags: c++, arduino

what I am trying to do is to program a Arduino Nano to control the ULN2003 driver to control the 28BYJ-48 stepper motor. I'm having trouble with the if/for statements and and getting the loop to break once it has done a specified number of rotations (i.e. 6). the way I want to actuate the motor is to have the photo sensor and the toggle switch. The toggle switch will be able to turn the stepper motor both CW and CCW. If the servo is all the way CCW it should not turn that way, and it should only turn CW if the photo resistor has not already caused the servo to turn CW.The photo resistor will only ever cause the motor to turn one direction, CW, and it will only do so if the toggle switch(button) has not already put it to that position.

```
#include <Stepper.h>

const int stepsPerRevolution = 2048,switchpin = 12,switchpinout=6;  
int buttonPin = 3,buttonRead,dt=500,switchstate=0;

Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 10, 9, 11);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Speed is variable up 10, 11 starts to make issues 
  myStepper.setSpeed(10);
  pinMode(buttonRead,INPUT);
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(switchpin, INPUT);
  pinMode(switchpinout, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {
  Serial.println(buttonRead);
  Serial.println(analogRead(A0));

  if ((analogRead(A0)>940))&&(switchstate==LOW))//sensor on switch off 
  {
  myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution*6);
  return 0;
  }
  else if (analogRead(A0)<940)&&(swithstate==LOW))//sensor off switch off
  {
  myStepper.step(-stepsPerRevolution*6);
  return 0;
  }
  else if (analogRead(A0)<940)&&(swithstate==HIGH))//sensor off switch on 
  {
  myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution*6);
  return 0;
  }
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: What "for statements" are you talking about? I don't see any in your code? The `loop()` function is run by your Arduino _over and over_ because that's how it works. You can't stop the execution of the `loop()`, but you can detect the conditions under which it should do nothing and then `return;` out of the function if said conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to check the sensor after every step (for best safety):

```
int loop ()
{
  //...
  for (int i = 0; i < ROTATION_COUNT; ++i)
  {
     if (/* sensor not triggered */)
     {
         AdvanceStepperMotor(1);
         Delay();  // Wait for the step to complete.
     }
     else
     {
        break;
     }
  }
  return 0;
}
```